# Smartclt - No self-tests have been logged

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Good night,

The following command is scheduled in the crontab: 15 10,13,19,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/smartctlLogger.sh

```
smartctl -i -l selftest -l error -H -t short
```

However, in one of the tests performed at 23, there was the following return:

SMART Self-test lo g structure revision number 0
Warning: ATA Specification requires self-test log structure revision number = 1
No self-tests have been logged

Not showing the records below, as they usually appear in the log:

Warning: ATA Specification requires self-test log structure revision number = 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error

1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21258         -

2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21255         -

3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21252         -

4  Sho﻿rt offline       Completed without error       00%     21242         -
(...)

The disk is: Model Family: Quantum Fireball lct20, Device Model: QUANTUM FIREBALLlct20 20, Firmware Version: APL.0900.

My doubts are, because no self-tests have been logged (No self-tests have been logged), and because it also appears:

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 0
Warning: ATA Specification requires self-test log structure revision number = 1

Other disks appear only: SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1

Answer (score 0):

This is by IT standards an ancient disk (capacity of the family is 10GB up to 40GB, which is less than I have on my smartphone).

I expect that it does not comply to the current SMART specifications, which is why smartctl is complaining about the log revision number. You will probably have to live with it not supporting SMART correctly; replacing it is probably not an option as it predates the SATA interface.